# Browsers showing up cached joomla website despite clearing

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, joomla, cpanel

I'm trying to restore a akeeba backup on https://zovdisplays.com 
The website is showing up the cached contents on chrome, tried on Firefox as well. Cleared cookies and cache. Also flushed DNS

When i visit the url via a proxy server. I can see the akeeba restore setup.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an ISP cache. Try loading the domain from another ISP. If its loading the restored contents on a proxy server, it should reflect the changes to your browser once the ISP cache expires.